# Como usar o Remote Validation de forma correta?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando usar o `Remote Validation` para verificar se o email já esta cadastrado, o problema é que sempre que informo um email por exemplo `fernandopaiva@gmail.com` não me retorna que o email já esteja cadastrado e ele está cadastrado, e se eu coloco `fernandopaiva@gmail.com.br` ai retorna a validacao que o email ja esta cadastrado, muito estranho isso.

Como resolver esse problema ?

Estou tentando assim.

**Classe de Usuario**

```
[Serializable]
public class Usuario{

    public virtual long id              { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o nome")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Campo nome deve ter de 5 a 50 caracteres")]        
    public virtual String nome          {get;set;}

    [Remote("isExistEmail", "Usuario", ErrorMessage = "Email já cadastrado!")]
    [EmailBrasil(EmailRequerido=true)]        
    public virtual String email         {get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Informe a senha")]
    [SenhaBrasil(SenhaTamanhoMinimo = 8, SenhaTamanhoMaximo = 8, SenhaForteRequerida = false, CaracterEspecialRequerido = false)]
    public virtual String senha         {get;set;}

    public virtual int status           {get; set;} //1 ativo, 2 inativo, 0 aguardando

    public Usuario() { }

 }
```

**Método que verifica se o email está cadastrado no controller do usuário.**

```
public JsonResult isExistEmail(String email){
     Boolean isExist = dao.isExist(email);            
     if (isExist){                
         return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }else{
         return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
}
```

**DAO que verifica a existencia do email no banco de dados**

```
//verifica se ja existe o email cadastrado
public Boolean isExist(String email){
    ISession _session = getSession();
    IList<Usuario> list = _session.CreateQuery("FROM Usuario u WHERE u.email = :email")
       .SetParameter("email", email)            
        .SetMaxResults(1)
        .List<Usuario>();
    if (list.Count > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Email <img src="~/Imagens/required.png" height="6" width="6"></label>
      <div class="cols-sm-10">
          <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.email, new { Class = "form-control", placeholder = "Informe o email", maxlength = 255 })
          </div>
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, pelo que li na documentação quando existe a ocorrência, no caso o email, o retorno no JSON deve ser `false` e não `true` como eu estava tentando, fiz a mudança e funcionou 100%.

Fiz assim.

```
public JsonResult isExistEmail(String email){
            Boolean isExist = dao.isExist(email);            
            if (isExist){                
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }else{
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tente editar o registro?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editar o registro ?

Comment: Use a rotina agora para alterar o registro? É só uma preocupação...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não entendi bem o que vc diz para editar o registro. Mas o registro está sendo alterado normalmente, o email é unico para acesso ao sistema e o usuário nao pode alterar esse email. Mas sempre que vou alterar um registro eu pego ele na session do NHibernate e altero com o update. Ta blzinha isso, funcionando 100%

Comment: Ok fernando. Parabéns